# How to select linked flat faces directly?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, faces

Usually we must select (at least) one face
[image]

and then "Select Linked Faces" to get selected like this
[image]

Is there any way to select linked flat faces directly once you click on face?

like `Alt + LMB` to select edge loop quickly.

[EDIT]
Here the example that what I mean,
that is selection feature on rizomUV.
but its possible to do that in blender?
[image]

Comment: Hi :). The *Ctrl+L* shotcut is pretty quick

Comment: select one face and go to select>select similar.

there are lot of handy features like selection based on area of face and so on.

Comment: Go to _Linked Flat Faces_ in the _Select Linked_ menu, right-click on it and choose _Assign Shortcut_ to create your own shortcut. That's the easiest and quickest way I know.

Comment: @JachymMichal But _Ctrl_ + _L_ selects all linked faces, not only the flat ones.

Comment: @Gordon Oh you're right, I missed that. Gotta learn to read better :)

Comment: Ditto this. Will check the manual…

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, but this is not Shortcut matter (I already assigning),
I've edit my question with including example,
i hope is understandable.
thanks in advance :)